# Group Hash by values in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash in ruby which looks something like this:

```
{
  "admin_milestones"=>"1",
  "users_milestones"=>"0",
  "admin_goals"=>"1",
  "users_goals"=>"0", 
  "admin_tasks"=>"1", 
  "users_tasks"=>"0",
  "admin_messages"=>"1",
  "users_messages"=>"0",
  "admin_meetings"=>"1",
  "users_meetings"=>"0"
}
```

I am trying to lookout for a solutions which can cut this hash in to two parts, one with value as 1 and other hash with value as 0.

Comment: I was specifically looking for what the user has answered below, thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can group hash by its value:

```
h1 = {
  "admin_milestones"=>"1",
  "users_milestones"=>"0",
  "admin_goals"=>"1",
  "users_goals"=>"0", 
  "admin_tasks"=>"1", 
  "users_tasks"=>"0",
  "admin_messages"=>"1",
  "users_messages"=>"0",
  "admin_meetings"=>"1",
  "users_meetings"=>"0"
}

h2 = h1.group_by{|k,v| v}
```

It will produce a hash grouped by its values like this:

```
h2 = {"1"=>[["admin_milestones", "1"], ["admin_goals", "1"], ["admin_tasks", "1"], ["admin_messages", "1"], ["admin_meetings", "1"]], 
"0"=>[["users_milestones", "0"], ["users_goals", "0"], ["users_tasks", "0"], ["users_messages", "0"], ["users_meetings", "0"]]}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want an array as answer the cleanest solution is the partition method.

```
zeros, ones = my_hash.partition{|key, val| val == '0'}
```

Comment: This one's much better solution.

Comment: Note: Partition only works for boolean separation in two buckets (true and false). It does not work if you want to split into many categories.

Comment: {a: '0', b: '1', c: '2'}.partition {|key, val| val == '0'}
# returns [[[:a, "0"]], [[:b, "1"], [:c, "2"]]]
I was hoping the array would be an array of hashes

Answer (score 5):

You should use `group_by` on the `keys` arrays and use the value as the grouping element:

```
h1 = {
  "admin_milestones"=>"1",
  "users_milestones"=>"0",
  "admin_goals"=>"1",
  "users_goals"=>"0", 
  "admin_tasks"=>"1", 
  "users_tasks"=>"0",
  "admin_messages"=>"1",
  "users_messages"=>"0",
  "admin_meetings"=>"1",
  "users_meetings"=>"0"
}

# group_by on the keys, then use the value from the hash as bucket
h2 = h1.keys.group_by { |k| h1[k] }

puts h2.inspect
```

Returns a hash from value to array of keys:

```
{
    "1" => [
        [0] "admin_milestones",
        [1] "admin_goals",
        [2] "admin_tasks",
        [3] "admin_messages",
        [4] "admin_meetings"
    ],
    "0" => [
        [0] "users_milestones",
        [1] "users_goals",
        [2] "users_tasks",
        [3] "users_messages",
        [4] "users_meetings"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nice!
Groups the collection by result of the block. Returns a hash where the keys are the evaluated result from the block and the values are arrays of elements in the collection that correspond to the ke

Answer (score 3):

Just `Hash.select`:

```
h1.select { |key, value| value == '0' } #=> {"users_milestones"=>"0", "users_goals"=>"0", ...}
h1.select { |key, value| value == '1' } #=> {"admin_milestones"=>"1", "admin_goals"=>"1", ...}
```

The return value depends on your Ruby version. Ruby 1.8 returns a array of arrays, whereas Ruby 1.9 returns a hash like in the example above.

Comment: This answer required the code to go through the hash twice.  Probably not an issue for short hashes, but something to be aware of

Answer (score 0):

Similar with https://stackoverflow.com/a/56164608/14718545 you can use `group_by` but with `then`, in this case, you will avoid instantiating an extra variable.

```rb
{
  "admin_milestones" => "1",
  "users_milestones" => "0",
  "admin_goals" => "1",
  "users_goals" => "0",
  "admin_tasks" => "1",
  "users_tasks" => "0",
  "admin_messages" => "1",
  "users_messages" => "0",
  "admin_meetings" => "1",
  "users_meetings" => "0"
}.then { |h| h.keys.group_by { |k| h[k] } }
```

```rb
{"1"=>["admin_milestones", "admin_goals", "admin_tasks", "admin_messages", "admin_meetings"],
 "0"=>["users_milestones", "users_goals", "users_tasks", "users_messages", "users_meetings"]}
```