# Access parent through child in view using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Field with children Topics. Topics are given to posts and I want to display the Fields which topics are children of (e.g If a post has the topics 'rofl', 'lol' and 'lmao' and all of these topics belonged to the parent 'Internet abbreviations').

I want to display something like this:

```
INTERNET ABBREVIATION rofl lol lmao
```

Here is the code from the view.

```
  <div class="fields">
  <% reading.topics.each do |topic| %>
    <span class="indivfields">
    <%= link_to topic.field.name, field_path(topic.field) %>
    </span>

  </div>

  <div class="subjects">
    <% reading.topics.each do |topic| %>
    <span class="indivsubjects"> <%= link_to topic.name,field_topic_path(topic.field,topic) %></span>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
```

The problem is because the first `reading.topic.each do` is topic and not field so, continuing the example above, the output I end up with is this:

INTERNET ABBREVIATION rofl lol lmao

INTERNET ABBREVIATION rofl lol lmao

INTERNET ABBREVIATION rofl lol lmao

It prints based on the number of children and I want this to display once. Thanks!

Comment: Does topic have_many subjects? If so you can iterate over the `topic` variable. Inside the `reading.topics.each` block, you can do `topic.subjects.each do |subject|` and print each subject there. Check out `render collection`, might help you: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render.

Comment: As an aside, your code sample looks amiss. Should the first `<div>` be inside the `.each do` loop?

Comment: Daryll, subjects is the div name I am using. So what I have set up is a Field has many subjects. But then a 'post' has many topics through a join table so it looks a bit like this: Field - Topics - Classify(join table) - Post. And yeah mbratch, thanks, my divs pretty far off being correct arent they. I was just trying to organise it in my head but have done a bad job.

Comment: @DaryllSantos If i try what you suggest I end up with: `field name, topic name, field name again, second topic name, field name again, third topic name`. What i need to do is something like this: <% reading.topics.fields.each do |topic| %> but I cannot do that

Comment: You want field name, then first topic second topic third topic?

Comment: Correct @DaryllSantos

Comment: @DaryllSantos I dont really get why I can use topic.field.name in the post index view to show the field a topic is in yet i cannot use that in this way : `<% reading.topics.fields.each do |topic| %>`

Comment: Can't you start with topics.fields? That way you iterate down the correct path (one topic to many fields) rather than the many to one (many fields to one topic).

Comment: @DaryllSantos `<% reading.topics.each do |topic| %>` works which is what i have now. `<% reading.topics.fields.each do |topic| %>` does not work which is what you are suggesting I think. I just get "undefined method `fields' " Also, one topic does not have many fields. A topic has only one field. but a post can have various topics which may belong to different fields

Comment: How about adding has_many fields to post?

Comment: @DaryllSantos Then what? wouldnt I need another new join table to work that? I dont see why it is necessary since I can access the field names already through topics. I just dont want to display the fields and topics based on the number of topics but on the number of fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have an answer for you all. One of my classes is still poorly named using the 'indiv' abbreviation so please forgive me for that. I needed to use the group_by method. Here is the code:

```
  <% reading.topics.group_by(&:field).each do |fields, topics| %>
    <%= link_to fields.name, field_path(fields), class: "individualfields" %>


    <div class="subjects">
    <%= topics.collect { |t| link_to t.name, field_topic_path(fields, t), class: "indivsubjects"  }.join.html_safe  %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

And thats it. Thanks for getting to this answer must go to various people on the Rails IRC channel. It worked out very nicely because this code is actually smaller than my previous code for rending topics alone, and this renders fields and topics.

Answer (score 0):

Reading has_many field has_many topics it seems. I would structure the models like this:

```
class Reading
  has_many :fields
  has_many :topics
end

class Field
  belongs_to :reading
  has_many :topics
end

class Topic
  belongs_to :reading
  belongs_to :field
end
```

That way you can do `reading.fields.each`:

```
<%= reading.fields.each do |field| %>
  <h1><%= field %>
  <%= field.topics.each do |topic| %>
    <p><%= topic %></p>
```

Why? Because you want to have your software to map the domain model (or how things are in the real world) as much as possible. It just seems intuitive, even from an outsider perspective, that a post have the option to be categorized by Field and Topic.

For our application we do the same thing. We have Questions, which have Subjects and Topics, and Topics belong to Subject. Same database schema as the one I have above (just different names).

However if that didn't make sense (hehe) the other ways to solve this are to do a `group` to move up the models from Topic to Field. Involves SQL (check this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group), and grouping via a hash ([Group Hash by values in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841698/group-hash-by-values-in-ruby)). Sorry if I am not as helpful as I can, I am a bit tired now.

By the way I suggest don't do random abbreviations like indiv. I know it is in your best intention, and it sounds intuitive to abbreviate `individual` to `indiv`, but it's just best coding practice to not have random abbreviations, maybe someone else will join you in the coding and they might think about what `indiv` is. (I don't have the article to Clean Code but check this out: http://agileinaflash.blogspot.com/2009/07/abbreviations.html)

Comment: Thing is. Reading does not have many fields. Only topics. And to implement your suggestion would require another join table as well as the one I have for the relationship between readings and topics which seems a bit overkill to just display the fields the topics belong to once per field rather than once per topic. Is there no way to do something like (render field name if field name has not been rendered) or something?