# How to combine similar fields parsed from CSV using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am parsing baseball statistics from a CSV file, and I need to account for players who played for multiple teams within a season. Currently my code looks like this:

```
require 'CSV'

CSV.foreach("Batting-07-12-resaved.csv",{:headers=>:first_row}) do |row|
    if row[7].to_i != 0 && row[5] != 0 && row[1].to_i == 2009
        avg = row[7].to_f / row[5].to_f
        puts row[0] + ": " + avg.round(3).to_s[1..-1]
    end
end
```

The CSV headers look like this, and a player is identified by a key that sort of looks like their name and may recur based on different teams they played for (here are a few of the lines, copied from formatted file):

```
playerID    yearID  league  teamID  G   AB  R   H   2B  3B  HR  RBI SB  CS
aardsda01   2012    AL  NYA 1                                   
aardsda01   2010    AL  SEA 53  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
aardsda01   2009    AL  SEA 73  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
aardsda01   2008    AL  BOS 47  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
aardsda01   2007    AL  CHA 25  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
abadfe01    2012    NL  HOU 37  7   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
abadfe01    2011    NL  HOU 28  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
abadfe01    2010    NL  HOU 22  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
abercre01   2008    NL  HOU 34  55  10  17  5   0   2   5   5   2
abercre01   2007    NL  FLO 35  76  16  15  3   0   2   5   7   1
abreubo01   2012    AL  LAA 8   24  1   5   3   0   0   5   0   0
abreubo01   2012    NL  LAN 92  195 28  48  8   1   3   19  6   2
```

So, for example, the bottom two lines, Bobby Abreu played for two different teams in the 2012 season.

How could I combine the numbers from these two rows under the same `playerId` for the 2012 season to calculate his 2012 batting average?

Comment: Your question isn't well asked. You have the basic code to read the file, but you need to show your attempt to solve the particular problem. Without that it looks like you didn't try and you want us to write the "hard" code for you. Instead, try, try again, do it again, then finally ask a detailed question about that specific problem. See "[mcve]" and  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate: you're looking to do this effectively — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841698/group-hash-by-values-in-ruby

Comment: You need to learn about the differences between arrays and hashes, and their uses. They are basic building blocks and misusing or confusing them can make a fairly simple problem turn into a nightmare. Also, CSV stands for "comma separated values". Your file would be TSV (tab separated values). The CSV can handle them both, with a minor tweak when you start the parsing, but the terminology is important to get right, especially if you get into data processing and databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a data structure that holds data about each `playerID` as you iterate through the CSV data.  Using a hash would be perfect. [ruby-doc.org manual page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html)

```
require 'CSV'

# Hashes are built into ruby.  Using a hash literal 
# is more idomatic than h = Hash.new() */
h = {}  

CSV.foreach("Batting-07-12-resaved.csv",{:headers=>:first_row}) do |row|
    if row[7].to_i != 0 && row[5].to_i != 0 && row[1].to_i == 2009
        playerData = h[row[0]]
        if (!playerData) 
            playerData = [row[0], row[7].to_f, row[5].to_f]
        else
            playerData = [row[0], row[7].to_f+playerData[1], row[5].to_f+playerData[2]]
        end 

        h[row[0]]=playerData
    end
end

h.each {|key, value| 
    puts "#{value[0]} is #{value[1]/value[2]}" 
}
```

Comment: I don't know if `row[5] != 0` will ever evaluate to false. It probably needs to be `row[5].to_i != 0`.

Comment: Rather than `Hash.new()` use `{}`. The first form is great when you have to specify default values or use the block form, otherwise `{}` is idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for the critiques.  I updated my sample code with the more idiomatic hash construction (but left a comment to illustrate that it is not magic).  The `row[5] != 0` conversion might actually work due to type coercion, but it is definitely ugly, so I added a `.to_i`.